# Is there any game we can use in our profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, fun, tour

In Stackoverflow, the user called [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) use Towers of Hanoi problem on his profile. Looks like he used some JavaScript or something. Looks like he built this game for himself. But I want to ask, is there any game we can use on our profile page?

[image]

Comment: O.O How did he do that?  We can have JavaScript in our profiles?  Sounds like a security risk.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's just a trick with referrer strings and a script-generated image.

Comment: @TimStone: HAX!  That's awesomely clever :-)

Comment: Related: [Create a User-Profile Mini-Game](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game) (But [Shog9 is right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163844/is-there-any-game-we-can-use-in-our-profile#comment476968_163845)!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That user played something clever with image tags:

```
<h2>Towers of Hanoi</h2>

<p><img src=""http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/text"" />
<p>
<a href=""http://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?1""><img src=""http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/1"" /></a>
<a href=""http://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?2""><img src=""http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/2"" /></a>
<a href=""http://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?3""><img src=""http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/3"" /></a>
<p>
<a href=""http://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?reset"">Reset</a></p>
```

The `hanoi.php` script probably looks at the referrer header when your browser loads the images and generates images based on the query string on his own profile URL, plus a PHP session cookie.

The owner of that profile [challenged others to create their own](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game), resulting in a few more pretty cool cookie+image+referrer-parsing images.

None of these are in any way official.

Comment: That is an awesome hack!  Now to make my own!  TO THE PHP CAVE!

Comment: [Another user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) *did* have a snazzy tic-tak-toe game in his profile, but he replaced it with boring text. @Soner, it's a site for programmers - show off your skills by writing your own!

Comment: [Yes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game), 6 no less, @Soner ;-)